# Unknown background color in light slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm currently working on a Responsive E-Commerce Product Slider Using HTML CSS & JavaScript.
Which inlcudes jQuery Core 3.6.0 from https://code.jquery.com/ and light slider from http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/

I've managed to get it working, **however there is this random background color always allpied to the most left slide.**
[image]
At first i thought that i ay have accidentlly applied background color to it. But then i realized if one of the slide has a background color all of them shoud've. and it's always on the most left one.

I've checked the color code using paint (which is rgb(231,155,155)  it's also not in any of my colors in the rest of the html.
[image]

I've try to search the files using keyword("color") where it could've caused this. But i just can't seems to find it.

I've also checked my own scss file for any possible reason but both the slideshow container and the slide
doesn't even have a back ground property set to them.

Much Appreciate to anyone who can provide assistant.

Comment: Since there is no code for us to look at. Try right clicking on the slider element and selecting "inspect". This should show you the properties applied to the element along with the name of the file its coming from.

There is a chance any of the JavaScript file is applying the style.

Comment: Thank you so much Ahsan i just find it. it's somehow linked to another groups color code with rgba so that's why paint give a different rgb color.

Answer (score 0):

So i find the problem and i'm posting it here if anyone ran into the same problem.

So currently i have two slide show in my html and one of them has a groups of dot on the bottom of the slide show displaying which image is it displaying out of all.

By doing that it is set to 'active' and in the other slide(the one above) the most left slide is also set to 'active' by  sachinchoolur (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/).

so all i did was change one of the 'active' to 'activedot'

```
.active,.dot:hover {
    background-color: rgb(238, 160, 160);
}
```

to

```
.activedot,.dot:hover {
    background-color: rgb(238, 160, 160);
}
```

and in the corospoinding **javascript file** change the 'active' to 'activedot'